# MATLAB: Converting a 3 channel 24 bit bmp image into 1 channel 16 bit bmp image

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to do some image processing on an image like this:

[image]

It is a 24 bit BMP image.

In MATLAB I got the following info:

```
>> x = imread('1.bmp');  
>> size(x)

ans =

   200   150     3
```

This shows it has 3 channels , one for each of R , G and B.

It means each pixel will have three components of 8 bit each.

What I want to do is convert this image to 16 bit, one channel (i,e one color) using MATLAB  or OpenCV, and then do some image processing. My image processing algorithm is working on 16 bit images.

Comment: Do you mean like [rgb2gray](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html), or something different?

Comment: @RogerRowland It is not clear how many bits per pixel will be there in the resulting image (from rgb2gray).

Comment: It will be `double` after the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the image is grayscale even in RGB you just need one of the channels to have the grayscale image. you can also use [rgb2gray()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html) function.

Then, you can use [im2uint16()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/im2uint16.html) to convert it to 16 bits unsigned int image.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. BTW how do I save this final 16 bit image? And this would be the image that I will be sending to my boss.

Comment: `imsave` is used to save an image that is displayed in a figure window or stored in a handle. Use `imwrite` if you have a variable containing image data.

Comment: opps, thats what i meant.I didnt even check, sorry.

Comment: @AnderBiguri - No worries :) Just trying to help!